# Strategy to recover from Speech recognition errors in a Android application

Tags: android

I am trying to make an [speech recognition enabled application](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/speech-input.html) on Google Android, mainly for user experience. But during the testing stages I found that since there is misclassification , it can actually bring down user experience unless there is a good way to prevent it. What are some good ways in terms of programming and UI integration to handle mis-classifications?